# Fermi level of metal

Tags: circuit-analysis, physics, electron, fermi

Do metals have fermi level? As we know conduction band and valence band are overlaped for a metal. Does it make any sense for metals to have fermi level?

Comment: Excuse me, may i ask, what did confuse you? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_level

Comment: I wonder whether it's appropriate to add the semiconductors tag, since the question is not about semiconductors, and does not mention semiconductors, but is still very relevant to semiconductors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not? The Fermi level can be thought of as being related to the average electron energy. It may or may not lie within a band gap, and electrons may or may not be present at the energy, depending on whether or not there are available states for those electrons to occupy. Since metals lack a band gap at the Fermi level, there are available states for electrons to occupy at the Fermi level, unlike for typical semiconductors.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

That's about all I know - but the description of how [Schottky diodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal%E2%80%93semiconductor_junction) work invokes the Fermi level of the metal contact to explain why they work.

[image]

(from [Wikipedia Commons](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cc/Schottky_barrier_zero_bias.svg/800px-Schottky_barrier_zero_bias.svg.png))

Comment: Thank you for answering!